# charAt when used to determine unique characters

Tags: java

I am reviewing a problem of trying to determine if all characters in a string are unique. Here is the algorithm

```
public static boolean unique(String s) {
    if(s.length() > 128) {
        return false;
    }
    boolean[] char_set = new boolean[256];
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int val = s.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(i + ": " + val);
        if(char_set[val]) { // already found this char in string
            return false;
        }
        char_set[val] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In particular, my source of ambiguity is at the line:

```
int val = s.charAt(i);
```

From my understanding, ASCII characters have 128 unique characters. Is `s.charAt(i)` simply returning the index of the character within the ASCII string?

Using the example string of `12310`

I get the following value for `val`:

```
0: 32
1: 49
2: 50
3: 51
4: 49
```

I am totally confused as to where the value `32`, `49`, etc, came from, if it isn't the index of the char of the ASCII string.

Comment: See http://www.asciitable.com/: 32 is the space character, 49 is '1', etc. Note that Java characters are not limited to ASCII.

Comment: 0: 49
1: 50
2: 51
3: 49
is  what i got! so yah there is a space in your string

Comment: As commented above, probably there is a space in your string. The output should be 0: 49 1: 50 2: 51 3: 49 4: 48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my understanding, ASCII characters have 128 unique characters. Is
>   s.charAt(i) simply returning the index of the character within the
>   ASCII string?

nope, `String#charAt` returns the char value at the specified index. [Find more in documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-).

And 32, 49, ... are char ascii values.

Comment: What is a `char value`?

Comment: Perfect. That's what I thought as well. What method would I use if I simply wanted to get the character at that particular index?

Comment: `char` is actually a numeric type containing the unicode value. `char c = s.charAt(i);`, now char c hold the character of index i

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the ASCII value of the character.  In memory, there is no difference between a primitive char and a primitive int.  I made a small change to your code that should make it easier to understand as well as a test to demonstrate.
    @Test
    public void testGetUnique() {
        unique(" 12301");
        unique("0123456789");
        unique("abcdefghijklmnop");
        unique("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP");
    }

```
public static boolean unique(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    if(s.length() > 128) {
        return false;
    }
    boolean[] char_set = new boolean[256];
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        int val = c;
        System.out.println("i:" + i + " c:" + c + " " + val);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And the output is 
 1230

```
1
i:0 c:  32
i:1 c:1 49
i:2 c:2 50
i:3 c:3 51
i:4 c:0 48
i:5 c:1 49
0123456789
i:0 c:0 48
i:1 c:1 49
i:2 c:2 50
i:3 c:3 51
i:4 c:4 52
i:5 c:5 53
i:6 c:6 54
i:7 c:7 55
i:8 c:8 56
i:9 c:9 57
abcdefghijklmnop
i:0 c:a 97
i:1 c:b 98
i:2 c:c 99
i:3 c:d 100
i:4 c:e 101
i:5 c:f 102
i:6 c:g 103
i:7 c:h 104
i:8 c:i 105
i:9 c:j 106
i:10 c:k 107
i:11 c:l 108
i:12 c:m 109
i:13 c:n 110
i:14 c:o 111
i:15 c:p 112
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
i:0 c:A 65
i:1 c:B 66
i:2 c:C 67
i:3 c:D 68
i:4 c:E 69
i:5 c:F 70
i:6 c:G 71
i:7 c:H 72
i:8 c:I 73
i:9 c:J 74
i:10 c:K 75
i:11 c:L 76
i:12 c:M 77
i:13 c:N 78
i:14 c:O 79
i:15 c:P 80
```

So space is 32, 0 is 48 and it increases by one up to 57.  'A' is 65, and you add one per letter after that.  'a' is 97, same deal.